How to use array data in ForEach controller ? Getting data list in one thread group and using that variable in another thread's forEach controller
Getting equipmentNumber from json extractor in thread one and want to use that data for multiple user in another thread. As that equipmentNumber has multiple data like equipmentNumber1, equipmentNumber2...etc.
currently using ForEach controller
enter image description here

Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! Please read how to ask a good question.

In order to be able to use variables from one Thread Group in another Thread Group you will need to convert them into JMeter Properties. See Functions and Variables user manual chapter for more information on properties and variables
It can be done using i.e. a suitable JSR223 Test Element and the following code:

In Thread Group 1:
vars.entrySet().findAll { var -> var.getKey().startsWith('equipmentNumber') }.each { var -> props.put(var.getKey(), var.getValue()) }


In Thread Group 2:
props.entrySet().findAll { prop -> prop.getKey().startsWith('equipmentNumber') }.each { prop -> vars.put(prop.getKey(), prop.getValue()) }



More information: Using JMeter Variables With Multiple Thread Groups
